# Issues with video size and WebRTC

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I am trying to use WebRTC to get access to the mobile camera. I have set it up according to what I found online. However, I am running into a few issues.

- My code doesn't seem to work on Android devices.
- When I try to set the `width` and `height` properties of the video it doesn't work.
- On iOS when I view the video. Then leave the Safari app for a few seconds. Then return to the page the video has black on the sides / changed aspect ratio?

Anyone know how to fix these issues / has a better implementation?

**ILLUSTRATIONS**

[image]

**MY CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <video id="video"></video>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var video; // INPUT WEBRTC as <video> tag
        var cameras = ["user", "environment"]; // USUAL CAMERA TYPES

        var options = []; // CAMERAS AVAILABLE
        navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((devices) => {
            let index = 0;
            devices.find((device) => {
                if (device.kind === 'videoinput') {
                    if (device.deviceId == '') {
                        options.push({
                            audio: false,
                            video: {
                                facingMode: {
                                    exact: cameras[index]
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        index++;
                    } else {
                        options.push({
                            audio: false,
                            video: {
                                deviceId: {
                                    exact: device.deviceId
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            if (options.length == 0) {
                console.log("NO DEVICES FOUND");
            } else {

                navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(options[options.length - 1]).then(stream => {

                    video = document.getElementById("video");
                    video.setAttribute('playsinline', 'playsinline');
                    video.setAttribute('position', 'absolute');
                    video.setAttribute('top', '0');
                    video.setAttribute('left', '0');

                    document.body.appendChild(video);

                    try {
                        video.srcObject = stream;
                        video.style.display = 'block';
                        video.play();
                    } catch (error) {
                        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                        video.style.display = 'block';
                        video.play();
                    }

                    // TRYING TO CHANGE VIDEO SIZE BELOW DOESN'T WORK

                    /*
                    var w = window.innerWidth;
                    var h = w * (video.videoHeight / video.videoWidth);

                    video.width = w;
                    video.height = h;
                    */
                })
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A simple answer to this issue is use of `object-fit` property of CSS within your video container.

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer to this issue is use of `object-fit` property of CSS within your video container.

`object-fit` property allow your video or images to render within specified area using crop functionality. It is good choice to use `object-fit:cover`. But if you are going to use screen-sharing functionality as well make sure to set `object-fit` property value to `fill` to render full screen avoiding crop functionality otherwise it will crop your shared screen video to center.

Example:

```
<video style="object-fit:cover; width:320px; height:240px"></video>
```

You can read more about this property usage here:

[object-fit property](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp)

Comment: there is a problem with this solution, because you are going to not show the real picture and just try to fit it.